# Spark Structured Streaming - Custom aggregation with window time event

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, spark-structured-streaming

I am trying to do custom aggregation on a structured streaming with event time windowing.
First I have tried to use #Aggregator interface (typed-UDAF) with the .agg function, something like :

```
val aggregatedDataset = streamDataset
  .select($"id",$"time", $"eventType", $"eventValue"))
  .groupBy(window($"time", "1 hour"), $"id").agg(CustomAggregator("time","eventType","eventValue").toColumn.as("aggregation"))
```

Yet this aggregation (in reduce function) is only working on the new input element, not the whole group

So I am trying to use the GroupState function (mapGroupsWithState, flapMapGroupWithState), or even just mapGroups function (without the state) to perform my aggregation

But my groupBy operation returns RelationalGroupedDataset and I need a KeyValueGroupedDataset to use map functions. groupByKey does not work with windowing.

How can I manage to do a custom aggregation with the structured streaming and timed event?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

GroupState function(s) - `mapGroupsWithState`, `flapMapGroupWithState`, or `mapGroups` (without the state) are used to perform an aggregation only when we need to operate in `Update` output mode.

But if we are using `Complete` output mode then we do not need GroupState functions.

So, if you change the output mode of `aggregatedDataset` query to `Complete`, then it will work as expected.

I hope it helps!

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response but actually I am already declaring the write stream with the complete output mode :    
val console = aggregatedDataset.writeStream
        .outputMode("complete")
      .option("truncate","false")
        .format("console")
        .start()

I think I am missing something.., I'll try with mapGroupWithState & update mode